# Building a List of 2D Polygons from a Datatable of Named Coordinates

Tags: c#, list, datatable, nested, polygon

I have a Datatable zct (zone/polygon coordinate table) with columns defined as:

```
private void buildZoneDataTable()
        {
            // Add columns to the DataTable.
            zct.Columns.Add("Zone Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            zct.Columns.Add("X_Coordinate", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
            zct.Columns.Add("Y_Coordinate", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
            coordDGV.DataSource = zct;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvcol in coordDGV.Columns)
            {
                dgvcol.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            }
```

Each row of the zct is coordinates for a vertex of a polygon that I'll later render, but for now my goal is to have a nested list of all the named zones/polygons and their polygon coordinates.

Here's what I have so far to create a single polyzone:

```
        private void BuildZoneList()
        {
            //iterate through all rows of the zct
            for (int i = 0; i < zct.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //if first row, or row I has a different name start new zone
                if(i == 0 || zct.Rows[i][0] != zct.Rows[i-1][0])
                {
                //create new polyzone named by the first column 
                 PolyZone pZone = new PolyZone(zct.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                }           
            }
        }
```

Here's a snippet of my polyzone class:

```
    public class PolyZone
    {

        public string polyZoneName;
        List<Point3D> pointList = new List<Point3D>(0);
        Point3D polyCenter = new Point3D(0,0,0);

        public PolyZone(string zoneName)
        {
            polyZoneName = zoneName;
        }

        public void add(Point3D point3D)
        {
            pointList.Append(point3D);

        }
```

EDIT: Thanks to jdweng for his answer, I'm able to get the zone names from the list but I'm having trouble getting the points to add to the list. Here's how I rewrote the BuildZoneList method:

```
        public List<PolyZone> BuildZoneList()
        {
            var zones = zct.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Zone")).ToList();
            List<PolyZone> listOfPolyZones = new List<PolyZone>();
            foreach(var zone in zones)
            {
                PolyZone newZone = new PolyZone(zone.Key);
                listOfPolyZones.Add(newZone);

                foreach(DataRow row in zone)
                {
                    double x = row.Field<double>("X_Coordinate");
                    double y = row.Field<double>("Y_Coordinate");
                    double z = ZoneyRender.elevation;
                    newZone.Add(new Point3D(x,y,z));
                }

            }
            return listOfPolyZones;
        }
```

And here's how I'm testing it:

```
private void listZonesAndCoordsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<PolyZone> listOfPolyZones = BuildZoneList();
            foreach(PolyZone zone in listOfPolyZones)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Zone:" + zone.polyZoneName);
                foreach(Point3D p3d in zone.pointList)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Zone:" + zone.polyZoneName + Environment.NewLine + p3d.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

The first mbox with the zone name comes up fine, but the mbox that's supposed to show the coordinates never pops up, making me think the list is empty. Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JonasH, sorry, your comment flew over my head, could you dumb it down for me? No SQL here.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I assumed the data source would be from a database, if not you can disregard my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
   class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           DataTable zct = new DataTable();
           zct.Columns.Add("Zone Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
           zct.Columns.Add("X_Coordinate", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
           zct.Columns.Add("Y_Coordinate", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
           zct.Columns.Add("Z_Coordinate", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));

           var zones = zct.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Zone Name")).ToList();
           List<PolyZone> polyZones = new List<PolyZone>();
           foreach (var zone in zones)
           {
               PolyZone newZone = new PolyZone(zone.Key);
               polyZones.Add(newZone);

               foreach (DataRow row in zone)
               {
                   double x = double.Parse(row.Field<string>("X_Coordinate"));
                   double y = double.Parse(row.Field<string>("Y_Coordinate"));
                   double z = double.Parse(row.Field<string>("Z_Coordinate"));
                   newZone.add(new Point3D(x, y, z));
               }
           }


        }
 
    }
    public class PolyZone
    {

        public string polyZoneName;
        List<Point3D> pointList = new List<Point3D>(0);
        Point3D polyCenter = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);

        public PolyZone(string zoneName)
        {
            polyZoneName = zoneName;
        }

        public void add(Point3D point3D)
        {
            pointList.Add(point3D);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this only got me half way there, can you check out my edits? Thanks!

Comment: Add data to the DataTable (not the DataGridView).  Your edits do not look like my code above.